# shell script: manipulate input

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have this simple create directory command

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /home/test/$1
```

I'm running this script like this

```
bash create.sh 2020/06/20/01
```

I want to get this passed argument and manipulate into following

```
2020-06-20/01
```

how can I do it

Comment: Probably lots of ways to achieve this, but off the top of my head sed string substition like `echo "2020/06/20/01" |sed 's!/!-!' |sed 's!/!-!'` will replace the first two forward slashes with dashes. Take a look at the man pages for `sed` (and `awk`) for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```bsh
date=${1%/*}                     # 2020/06/20
dirname=${date//\//-}/${1##*/}   # 2020-06-20/01
mkdir -p "/home/test/$dirname"
```

Or perhaps

```bsh
IFS=/ read -ra date_bits <<<"$1"   # date_bits=([0]="2020" [1]="06" [2]="20" [3]="01")
printf -v dirname "%s-%s-%s/%s" "${date_bits[@]}"
mkdir -p "/home/test/$dirname"
```